# Odoo sequence reset insist using UTC

Tags: odoo, sequence, odoo-8

I am using Odoo sequence for a form number. This sequence is set to reset every month. But I have noticed an issue in the sequence reset time.

The sequence turns out resetting every UTC not at server timezone which is UTC +8. So when a transaction happened at 1 July 7 AM (UTC + 8) the sequence is still not being reset. The reset happened on 1 July at 8 AM (UTC).

How can I make the sequence reset based on my timezone? The server timezone is already UTC + 8.

Answer (score 0):

Two Options:

1. Check the timezone of your database. Do this in your postgres db terminal with the command:

```
show timezone;
```

You should expect your local timezone or UTC

2. If you check the model behind the feature, in the postgress console:

```
 \d ir_sequence_date_range
```

You may notice that the fields related to the range of the dates (date_from, date_to) were created as "date" and not "datetime" so it gonna miss the hours.

Also, in the form view, the is not possible to set the time:
[sequence_form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCqeW.png)

So an alternative is change the data type of the column from date to datetime. To do this you must extend the model and over write the field something like this:

```
class IrSequenceDateRangeExtended(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.sequence.date_range'
    date_from = fields.Datetime(string='From', required=True)
    date_to = fields.Datetime(string='To', required=True)
```

Then, after update you should be able to set the time to the date.
I hope it helps you.

Comment: My postgres timezone is `Asia/Kuala Lumpur`. Do I need to change it to UTC?

Comment: I think it's fine if you don't have other related issues. I updated my answer with another approach.